# Change column type and set value depending on existing data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a nullable column `A` of type `boolean` with most of the values being `None`and some of them being `True`. I want to change this column to a `timestamp` column, and for all existing rows if the current value is not `None` then to set it to some default timestamp.

Is that possible? The only way I can think of is to create an intermediary column that holds the newly calculated values, change the type of `A`, copy over values from the new column, and then drop it.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Btw what value you like to set in timestamp column if the previous value is true. Are you planning to set current date? The only way is to add a new column and set its value based on value from old column. Then later drop the old column. Your approach should be good enough.

Comment: @Baskar doesn't really matter what I set it to, tbh. Was planning on setting it to start of unix time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes as all mentioned it is impossible to change the type of column.
You can add a new datetime column.

```
Update tablename set newcolumn = value where oldcolumn = true;
Update tablename set newcolumn = value where oldcolumn = none;
```

Later you can drop the old column. This is a pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that possible?

NO, cause your column data type currently is `boolean` and thus if you even use `ALTER` statement and change the type to `TIMESTAMP` ... how do you think you will change the existing row values which are `TRUE`? Since it's non convertible to `timestamp` datatype.

Only way I see, is creating a new column with `TIMESTAMP` datatype, update the table and fill that column and then drop the existing column `A`

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to force the `boolean` column to `Datetime` column if there exists bool data in column. I think the only only way you could do is to create a staging column with `datetime` column, update that column with the `bool` column then drop that `bool` column.